# MS Access Linked Excel Files Sometimes Open (Datasheet View), Sometimes Do Not Open

Tags: ms-access-2007, excel-2007

My company released a mandatory MS Office patch last month (March 2013) that has lowered the performance of MS Access.  I am using **`Office 2007`** and have several .ACCDB databases that have linked tables in .XLSM and .XLSX format.  Prior to the patch, these links worked without issues. Now however, when I try to open the tables in Datasheet view in Access (or use them in a query), Access sometimes opens the linked table successfully without a warning, sometimes opens the linked table in datasheet view with a warning, or sometimes gives the same warning but doesn't even open the table.  When the warning occurs, it reads:

`"Windows - Delayed Write Failed.  Windows was unable to save all the data for the file XXX.XLSX.  The data has been lost.  This error may be caused by a failure of your computer hardware or network connection.  Please try to save this file elsewhere"`

I have searched for this specific scenario on these forums without luck.  Does this sound familiar to anyone?  I can't tell if the problem is with Access, Excel, or the shared drive the DB/Files reside on.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Mostly occured when your HDD going bad..

Comment: i don't think it's the HDD, because this problem happened to everyone in the department who had the patch installed; could this have to do with Office 2010?

Comment: You mean they got same error too ?

Comment: yes, multiple users with different HDDs all receive the same error; but I can't pinpoint it based on the description: is it a network error/Office 2010/something else?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330174 or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321733 may give some you some pointers